# Why does this for loop not display in my div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the content in my div but the code won't work. Please show me how to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="display"></p>
    <script>
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        var disp = "the number is " + i;
        console.log(disp);
      }
      disp = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the loop to display my variable in my selected div? Which part of my code is wrong? please help.

Comment: document.getElementById("display").innerHTM = disp;

Comment: Please add proper indentation to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never write anything to your HTML page. You just display it in your console. And later you assign the HTML content of the #`display` element to the variable `disp`, which doesn't make any sense:

```
disp = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
```

This is how it will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="display"></p>
        <script>

        var i;
        for(i=0; i<11; i++){
            var disp = "the number is " + i;
            // This just writes to the javascript console
            console.log(disp);
            // This writes in the #display element on your page
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += disp + '<br>';
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tehre are multiple problems

```html
<p id="display"></p>

<script>
  var i;

  //initialize the value
  var disp = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    //concatenate the value of disp so that new value will be added to the previous content other wise the values will be overwritten
    disp += "the number is " + i;
    console.log(disp);

  }

  //assign value of disp to the elemet innerHTML
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = disp;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `innerHTML` inside the `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    var disp = "the number is " + i;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = disp;
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

**IF you want to display all the content at once**

```
var disp = ''; // Assign empty string
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    disp += " the number is " + i; // Concat message
}
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = disp; // Add into html
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;

    for(i=0; i<11; i++){

    var disp = "the number is " + i;
    console.log(disp);

    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = disp;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this should be fine](https://jsfiddle.net/p1wbm9oh/1/)

```
function createDivs(){
    var pContainer = document.getElementById("display");
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        var message = "the number is " + i;
        console.log(message);
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.innerHTML = message;
        pContainer.appendChild(element);
    }

    disp = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
};

createDivs();
```